# Is there any metadata modeler or semantic layer in Microsoft power BI

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi

what exactly i want to ask u is like

In congnos we are using frame work manager as metadata modeler and semantic layer 
similarly is there any tool or semantic layer  like frame work manager  in microsoft power BI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it's Power BI Desktop.  It has a Power Query (Query Editor) for data integrations,  Relationship View for table relationships, and Quick Measures backed by the DAX language for added calculations.  Here's some starting points for deeper info:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-query-overview/

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-relationship-view/

Published datasets can be resused on other reports.